# After adding SignalR package from Nuget in solution causing error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am having Single page Application with webapi which will communicate with SharePoint remotely.

I have added SignalR from Nuget packages and suddenly application started throwing below error on launch page itself

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Please find below stacktrace,

> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.]
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._GetPropertyOrFieldData(RuntimeModule
>   pModule, Byte** ppBlobStart, Byte* pBlobEnd, String& name, Boolean&
>   bIsProperty, RuntimeType& type, Object& value) +0
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetPropertyOrFieldData(RuntimeModule
>   module, IntPtr& blobStart, IntPtr blobEnd, String& name, Boolean&
>   isProperty, RuntimeType& type, Object& value) +105
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +1598
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, RuntimeType caType) +146
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute(String
>   friendlyName, IList1 errors, Boolean& conflict) +388
>
> Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.GetDefaultConfiguration(String
>   friendlyName,   IList1 errors) +130
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation(String startupName,
>   IList1 errorDetails) +241    Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load(String
>   startupName, IList1 errorDetails) +60
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() +348
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
>   +139 System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +241
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   context) +191
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +530
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +404
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +475
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618692
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159 System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12458309
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249

I have added assembly at location C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.dll.